# How do I use boot-strap and jQuery to toggle between two icons without buttons?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want it so that when a user clicks on the heart icon, the heart-icon is hidden and the heart-filled-icon is shown. How do I refer to the other icon within my jQuery function to change it's "display" from "none" to "shown"? I know that this example is really wrong this is just an idea of what I want to do and I can't figure it out.

```js
$('.heart-icon').click(function(){
  $('.heart-icon').hide();
  $('.heart-filled-icon').show();
});
```

```html
<svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="heart-icon bi bi-heart" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
</svg>
<svg width="1em" height="1em" style ="display:none;" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="heart-filled-icon bi bi-heart-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: use .toggle() for displaying and hiding, or .hide() to just hide and .show() to just show

Comment: just refer by .classname or #idname like $("#idname").show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways you can do this...

One way is to toggle the Bootstrap display classes. Put either `d-none` or `d-block` on the SVG's classes initially.

```
$('.bi').click(function(){
  $('.bi').toggleClass('d-none d-block');
})
```

https://codeply.com/p/FmVXaxOvoA

Comment: Thank you this works! But I have multiple instances of the icons. When i click one icon all of them are displayed/hidden. I tried using $(this).toggleClass( 'd-none d-block');}) but it didnt work.